# Memcached on Mac OSX fails when daemonizing second instance

Tags: macos, memcached, instances

i want to run memcache deamons on my local mac osx (latest os( machine for developing. when i start the first instance like:

```
sudo memcached -m 8mb -l localhost -p 11211 -d -vv
```

everything seems to be ok. if i make a lsof on the port this is how it looks like:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
memcached 614 root    4u  IPv4 0xffffff80113eeda8      0t0  TCP adobe-dns.adobe.com:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 614 root    5u  IPv6 0xffffff800c5c97b0      0t0  TCP localhost:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 614 root    6u  IPv6 0xffffff800c5c94a0      0t0  TCP localhost:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 614 root    7u  IPv4 0xffffff800c3b02c0      0t0  UDP adobe-dns.adobe.com:11211
memcached 614 root    8u  IPv6 0xffffff800c3af140      0t0  UDP localhost:11211
memcached 614 root    9u  IPv6 0xffffff800c3afa00      0t0  UDP localhost:11211
```

i find this quite strange ... and if i try the second instance on a new port like:

```
sudo memcached -m 8mb -l localhost -p 11212 -d -vv
```

i get an error saying:

failed to listen on UDP port 11211
udp listen: Address already in use

even though im starting the daemon on port 11212. can somebody explain or give any hints what this means - what is happening there

THX

Frank

Comment: *please* don't run memcached (or anything else where it isn't strictly required) as root.  That's just a terrible idea.  It does not help you, but will cause you problems.  memcached specifically tries to avoid having you do that.  If you're running an unmodified memcached, you didn't run it with that commandline because it would refuse to run as root (because that would be a terrible idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `-U 0` unless you care about UDP support, in which case you'd want to add `-U 11212`.  We straightened this out a bit more in later versions so it does something more intuitive.